# Plotly Gantt Chart, hover inside bar

Tags: plotly

The Gantt charts example of Plotly (examples are here: https://plot.ly/python/gantt/, https://plot.ly/r/gantt/) only show the hover text when on (or near) the **end-points** of the bars.

Is it possible to show the hover text when hovering inside the bars?

I tried to add: `hoveron = "points+fills"` (using the R version) but that did not help.

Thanks, Erwin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting [`hovermode = "y"`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-hovermode) in `layout` to get the hoverover popup when the mouse cursor is on the bar.

Modified example from [here](https://plot.ly/r/gantt/).

```
library(plotly)
df <- read.csv("https://cdn.rawgit.com/plotly/datasets/master/GanttChart-updated.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
df$Start <- as.Date(df$Start, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
client = "Sample Client"
p <- plot_ly() %>% layout(hovermode = "y")

for(i in 1:(nrow(df) - 1)){
  p <- add_trace(p,
                 x = c(df$Start[i], df$Start[i] + df$Duration[i]),
                 y = c(i, i),
                 type = "scatter",
                 mode = "lines",
                 line = list(width = 20),
                 showlegend = F,
                 hoverinfo = "text",
                 text = paste("Task: ", df$Task[i], "<br>",
                              "Duration: ", df$Duration[i], "days<br>",
                              "Resource: ", df$Resource[i])
  )
} 

p
```

[image]

Comment: Well almost. When enlarging the plot it looks like just the tolerance for finding the closest point is loosened. With a full-screen view we still have to be somewhat close to the end-points.

Comment: Strange, just tried with the example I posted in full screen mode and it still worked for any cursor position.